# Rewrite URLs with .htaccess but ignore specific Directories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a directory on a site:

- http://example.com/directory/

In it I have a .`htaccess` file.

I want it to take any URL like this:

- http://example.com/directory/section/day/

And rewrite it to:

- http://example.com/directory/index.php?arg1=section&arg2=day

Except for any URLs that refer to these directories:

- http://example.com/directory/css/
- http://example.com/directory/javascript/
- http://example.com/directory/images/

I have the first part working, but unable to tell it to exclude files in certain directories:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [NC]
```

**Update:**

This works in a very basic and simple sense:

```
RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^javascript - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^images - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [NC]
```

but I'm sure there is a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the keyword you're looking for is RewriteCond. It's pretty similar to what you ended up with.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(css|javascript|images)
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) index.php?arg1=$1&arg2=$2 [NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use `RewriteCond` to check if an actual file exists... at least, I use this for websites when I want things like CSS, Javascripts, and images to be accessible (without the request being redirected.)

Here's the line I use:

```
# only rewrite if the requested file doesn't exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
```

Let me know if that works for you!